# Cannot use keyboard within Qt app without sudo

Tags: linux, keyboard, c++, input, qt

I have an embedded Qt application crosscompiled that runs on BeagleBone Black. It works Ok, but one thing- It doesn't accept keyboard input if I won't run in directly on BeagleBone Black preceeding with `sudo`. This is a problem because:

- I cannot remote debug application and use connected keyboard, as it doesn't work,
- I cannot use keyboard when the app is in `rc.local` file to boot at startup (even though `sudo` is used there).

My `/etc/enviroment` content is here:

```
QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=IntelliMouse:/dev/input/mouse0
QWS_KEYBOARD=LinuxInput:/dev/tty
TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/ts
```

Although I have tried many different configurations for `QWS_KEYBOARD`. The keyboard I would like to use is `/dev/input/event1`.

Here are my persmissions:
My application rights are:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  353100 Mar  2  2015 OvenViewer
```

And the input device rights are:

```
crwxrwxrwt 1 root root 13, 65 Mar  1 21:45 event1
```

I have set the rights in a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-pure-data.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="event1", MODE="777"
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `/dev/input/event1` ? Are you using `udev` ? Please edit the question to improve it

Comment: I'm guessing this is Qt 4.x, given the `QWS_*` variables?  This is definitely version-dependent.

Comment: Yes this is Qt version 4.8. @BasileStarynkevitch I have created a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` where i added line `KERNEL=="event1", GROUP="keyboard", MODE="666"`. Then I added both user debian and root to group keyboard. didnt help :/

Comment: I have added some comments to the question